# UISearchDisplayController and table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

when I add a UISearchDisplayController from interface build, it comes with a search bar. what about the results table? do I need to add a UITableView myself, or is that already included?

which delegate methods do I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need to add a UITableView.

Also ensure your view controller has the appropriate UITableView delegate functions/methods (numberOfSectionsInTableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath and etc)

In addition look into implementing the UISearchDisplayDelegate and UISearchBarDelegate for your search bar.

[UISearchDisplayDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) [UISearchBarDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Do I also need to connect the datasource and delegate functions to UITableView?

Comment: and how does the UISearchDisplayController which one is its UITableView?

Comment: you don't have to connect the datasource and delegate functions in this instance, as long as your view controller has the appropriate delegate functions/methods. To setup the UISearchDisplayController you connect up the table and various things in interface builder for the UISearchDisplayController object.